# Calendar Clear button option is not working

Tags: html

I am trying to clear my selected date from the calendar, but clear button is not working. Where i find Today button is working fine, here is my code

```
<label for="dateOfBarth" class="control-label">Date of Birth *</label><input type="date" id="dateOfBarth" class="form-control" name="dob" placeholder="Select date" required="required">
```

[image]

Comment: removing `required="required"` should work.